# Is it possible to display an alert while app loading data and freezed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertview

I have an app that loads data from internet. While loading data from internet, app is freezing. Is it possible to display an alert view while loading? You can see the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: func above.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        let text = cell.textLabel?.text!
        let indexNumber = towersNameArray.indexOf(text!)
        PlayData.TowerAddress = towersAddressArray[indexNumber!] //Dataloading
        PlayData.TowerName = towersNameArray[indexNumber!] //Dataloading
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading...", message: "Please Wait", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            let delay = 2.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1


        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }



    }
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to load data on your main/UI thread. Use an async call for the data load

Answer (score 4):

You should load the data in a background thread like so:

```
//display an alert here if you need

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    //load stuff from internet here, don't display an alert

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        //display an alert here if you need to
    })
})

//display an alert here if you need.
```

Alternatively:

You could set a timer to fire after ~5 seconds before you start loading the content, and after the content finishes you could invalidate the timer. That way the timer will fire if the content does not load within 5 seconds, and if it loads faster, the timer will not fire.

```
func load() {
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "timerDone", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        //load stuff from internet here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.timer.invalidate()
        })
    })
}

func timerDone() {
    //display alert here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve it with another way, I moved the loading datas from internet part to dispatch part before the dismiss method. By using this way, the alert leaves when the data loads.(If I enter less time than loading time to timer)